# Wix modify existing control

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix-extension

I just started on Wix today, I want to modify "LicenseAgreementDlg" (I believe its a built-in dialog). I want to replace checkbox with Radio button.

I did some research and I think I have create a new wxs file with radio buttons.

Is this correct? Am I doing it right?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes. You must download the wix source, and modify the dialog to suite your needs. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887486/wix-custom-ui-for-sql-database-installation/10896867#10896867

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new dialog based on the standard one and replace it in the UI sequence.

See [Legalese](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/legalese/) in the [WiX tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/) for more details.