# Wix how to hide feature options

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I'm using Wix 3.5 to build a MSI installer.
I want to know if there is any way to hide some options from the "Features Custom Setup dialog" (in which you select from the Feature tree what to install).

I want to only have the options for "Will be installed on local hard drive" and "Entire feature will be  unavailable"

Currently, apart from those two options i have these options:

- "Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive"
- "Will be installed to run from network"
- "Entire feature will be installed to run from network"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Feature selection dialog uses [SelectionTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371604.aspx) control, a built-in control of the Windows Installer.

You can control which installation options are displayed for a feature using `Attributes` column of the [Feature Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371604.aspx).

[Feature element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_feature.htm) of WiX has four properties which control how a feature can be installed:

- Absent: allow / disallow
- AllowAdvertise: no / system / yes
- InstallDefault: followParent / local / source
- TypicalDefault: advertise / install

[Component table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007.aspx) also controls whether the component can be run from source or not. The Component element has `Location` property:

- *local*
  Prevents the component from running from the source or the network (this is the default behavior if this attribute is not set).
- *source*
  Enforces that the component can only be run from the source (it cannot be run from the user's computer).
- *either*
  Allows the component to run from source or locally.

So to remove the option to run from the network, set `Location` property of your components to `local`.

You cannot remove *Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive* from the options. It is displayed only when there are subfeatures and enables installation of the subfeatures as well as the feature itself as opposed from *Will be installed on local hard drive* which installs only the selected features and does not affect subfeatures.

If the subfeatures are always installed with the parent, you can try to set `InstallDefault` attribute of the subfeatures to `followParent`.

Comment: I have two separate features with not subfeatures, yet the "Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive" still appears. Why?

Comment: @Edgar Weird, it looks Windows Installer always displays _Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive_ even if there are not subfeatures. At least this item was present in all the cases that I tested where there were no visible subfeatures. It could also depend on the version of Windows Installer. Unfortunately I cannot provide anything more helpful.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. Could you add this comment to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28083142/wix-how-to-hide-feature-options-no-subfeatures

Answer (score 4):

To remove "This feature will be installed when required" set in your feature AllowAdvertise="no"
https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/custom-settings/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WiX UIExtension, then you need to download the WiX source code for that extension and modify it appropriately. The following links should help get you started:

[WiX UI Customizations](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm)

[Wix custom UI for SQL Database installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887486/wix-custom-ui-for-sql-database-installation)

[How to add a UI to a WiX 3 installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596919/how-to-add-a-ui-to-a-wix3-installer)

**UPDATE:**

Upon examining the WiX UI source, the FeaturesDlg displays a "SelectionTree" control. It appears that the control (along with the other controls displayed by the WiX UI) are Windows Installer controls, not WiX-specific controls. See [SelectionTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So it appears there is no easy way to just "turn off" those options.

Comment: I've been looking at the links, but it seems that there is no way to remove this options from the feature tree control. There is no mention on how to configure it.